# how do I change the Rails3 standard .gitignore file

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi
With Rails3 the rails new command creates a .gitignore file. As I have a few files from my editor that should be not committed, I don't want to add them to this standard gitignore file everytime I create a new rails application. How can I change the standard .gitignore file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a global .gitignore file in your home folder and put your ignores for your editor files in that. You need to run this command to get git to pickup the global gitignore file:

```
$ git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```

Comment: Do note that this only affects you. If you want to modify the default .gitignore for all users of the project, you're going to have to edit the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the gitgnore-file in your railties-gem

```
$GEMHOME/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/gitignore
```

But you must do it for every new version